AQPlayer could not be resolved
I'm having trouble adding AQPlayer as a package dependency in my app in XCODE. Here's the error that I get when I add it as a package.


Use pod 'AQPlayer'

The library you're trying to link against doesn't support SPM. It only supports Cocoapods. See the install section of the readme of the library for how to add is as a Cocoapods dependency.

Not every library supports SPM (Swift Package Manager) facility. If you notice, you get an error message as Package.swift does not exists. So you get the confirmation you can't add this library as a SPM. So either you add it on your project by cocoapod or you can directly drag and drop on you project as <framework_name>.framework or as <framework_name>.xcframework.
And make sure your library is getting display on your linked library section.
